# Access Sub-category without Parent Category

Tags: magento-1.8, category

We have following category and sub-category in our store.

`Category: http://yoursite.com/category.html`

`Sub-category: http://yoursite.com/category/sub-category.html`

Is it possible to access sub-category listing page using below URL

`Sub-category: http://yoursite.com/sub-category.html`

**Case 1 : Access sub-category listing page, even if its main category id disabled**

**Case 2: Access sub-category listing page without using main category in URL**

Also if my product is assigned to any `sub-category` and set the visibility to `Catalog`, will it appear on sub-category listing page when its category id disabled  ?

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Admin:

> Admin -> System -> Config -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations ->
>   Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs (set to NO)

Programmatically:

Open the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url` and comment the below line

```
//if (null === $parentPath) {
//    $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
//}
//elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
    $parentPath = '';
//}
```

under `function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)`

You can always create a local of your file, just in order to avoid over riding the core files

Comment: in magento ce  `Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs` option is not there

Answer (score 2):

we made this extension to do it

https://github.com/seansan/snh_settings_CategoryParentUrl

Up+1 if you like it

Answer (score 0):

i can recommend you to try below default function

Remove parent category path from url and change it from

**http://mysite.com/category/sub-category.html** to **http://mysite.com/sub-category.html**

**USAGE :**

Go to the **Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options**

Select **yes or no** from "`Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs`"

Refresh category url index

Option **YES** => http://mysite.com/category/sub-category.html

Option **NO** => http://mysite.com/sub-category.html

**Edit**

```
    <global>
        <models>
             <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_url>YourNamespace_Catalog_Model_Product_Url</product_url>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
   </global>
```

you can try to rewrite url for category. hope this could be work for you. i am not 100% sure about this modle url rewrite in `magento1.7`

Hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Liyakat is right.

Comment: @liyakat, `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` set to `yes`. Can not see the option you said i.e. `'Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs'`. Version is `1.7.0.2`

Comment: What should I do if I see no such option in my Mage admin ?

Comment: @Lazar, see my updated answer. And you can necessary changes in URL model of catalog

Comment: Where is this setting? (cannot find it in Magento 1.8.1)

Comment: @liyakat Is there code missing in your answer? I dont see any function

Comment: @snh_nl, i have given only the way you can achive, you should have to give your own input is well

Answer (score 0):

**To remove parent category path from child category url** 
Rewrite class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url`
override method `public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)` like below

```
public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)
{
    $storeId = $category->getStoreId();
    $idPath = $this->generatePath('id', null, $category);
    $suffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId);

    if (isset($this->_rewrites[$idPath])) {
        $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
        $existingRequestPath = $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();
    }

    if ($category->getUrlKey() == '') {
        $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getName());
    } else {
        $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getUrlKey());
    }

    $categoryUrlSuffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($category->getStoreId());
    // Code commented to remove parent category path from child category path
    //if (null === $parentPath) {
    //$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
    //}
    //elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
    $parentPath = '';
    //}
    $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,
        true, $category->getStoreId());

    $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
    if (isset($existingRequestPath) && $existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
        return $existingRequestPath;
    }

    if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($requestPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
        return $requestPath;
    }

    return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $requestPath,
        $this->generatePath('id', null, $category)
    );
}
```

Modified below code

```
if (null === $parentPath) {
    $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
} elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
    $parentPath = '';
}
```

to

```
//if (null === $parentPath) {
//    $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
//} elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
    $parentPath = '';
//}
```