# Remove parent category from category URL - but not for all categorys

Tags: category, url-rewrite, seo

We look for a solution, to remove parent category from url.

So normally the URL is -> `www.mydomain.com/specials/shoes.html`

but we need it like `www.mydomain.com/shoes.html`
it should be work for all the subcategories of "**specials**"

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25069/access-sub-category-without-parent-category check this maybe helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are using Magento CE 1.x and you want to avoid coding you can set this up by simply adding a custom URL rewrite for a category via **Admin/Catalog/URL Rewrite Management**.

If you want the cleaned URLs to show up in the Menu etc, you'll have to use an Overwrite (local Version or extended by Module) of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url::getCategoryRequestPath()`. Around line 723 the parent Path is inserted, you can simply avoid that by changing

```
$parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,true,$category->getStoreId());
```

to

```
$parentPath = '';
```

If you want to only change it for some category_ids (as your original question was) you can of course apply some Logic here to render $parentPath as empty string only if your Prerequisites are met.

Please be aware that putting some evaluation of Category Properties (like e.g. Product Count) will have a negative Impact on Performance.